# Get day of the week

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a basic segmented control that has an option for Monday-Sunday with different information being displayed as each one is selected.

My goal is to set the segmented control on initial load, to match the current day of the week. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the current weekday as integer with

```
NSInteger weekday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

In the gregorian calendar Sunday is represented by 1 --> Saturday: 7

You need to map the values to the actual indices of the segmented control.

Comment: Working perfect! Thank you very much.